# bptest doesn't seem to capture heterogeneity of the data

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, lm

Below are my data and code. The scatterplot shows that the independent variable is mostly clustered at the lower end of the scale, making the variance the largest there. The non-randomness of the residual is also shown in the residul vs fitted plot. But the bptest isn't significant. What am I not understanding here? Any help will be appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lmtest)

dependent_var <- c(3.07, 4.11, 2.26, 3.01, 3.69, 3.65, 3.61, 2.06, 3.55, 3.64, 3, 4.54, 2, 4.27, 2.81, 2.86, 2.64, 3.85, 2, 3.57, 2.38, 2.27, 4.19, 2.29, 4.37, 3.77, 3.96, 4.23, 4.28, 2.15, 3.83, 2.13, 2.97, 3.7, 3.9, 2.56, 3.82, 3.79, 3.56, 3.67, 4.18, 3.31, 4.11, 2.7, 3.75, 4.12, 4.29, 4.26, 4.23, 2.61, 3.5, 3.03, 4.56, 2.72, 3.8, 2.04, 2.84, 2.07, 2.03, 4.04, 3.78, 1.87, 2.35, 2.88, 1.96, 2.99, 2.21, 2.4, 2.58, 4.13, 3.27, 2.47, 4.32, 2.16, 3.01, 4.26, 3.17, 2.84, 3.09, 2.64, 3.02, 2.53, 2.58, 3.8, 1.84, 3.3, 2.09, 3.39, 4.39, 2.44, 2.74, 1.94, 2.49, 2.77, 3.2, 2.26, 1.99, 2.22, 2.35, 2.22, 2.09, 2.02, 2.54, 2.75, 4.03, 2.47, 2.32, 2.1, 2.6, 2.41, 3.16, 3.17, 1.91, 2.48, 3.83, 2.89, 1.82, 4.06, 3.84, 2.67, 2.1, 2.78, 3.32, 3.76, 1.76, 3.4, 3.71, 2.9, 2.41, 1.96, 2.71, 2.44, 2.36, 2.88, 4.16, 2.67, 2.68, 1.94)
independent_var <- c(1.22, 0.19, 2.21, 0.39, 1.2, 2.82, 0.35, 0.45, 0.08, 0.32, 0.46, 0.24, 0, 4.37, 0.07, 0.3, 0.9, 0.16, 0.26, 0.54, 0.18, 0.46, 0, 0.07, 1.96, 0.1, 0.83, 0.19, 0.25, 1.07, 0.79, 0.66, 1.12, 0.62, 1.29, 0.14, 0.21, 0.24, 1.45, 0.48, 0.16, 1.57, 1.12, 0.7, 3.89, 2.96, 0.19, 0.18, 0.15, 0.27, 1.11, 0.74, 0.34, 0.42, 0.87, 0.59, 0.24, 0.1, 0.23, 1.93, 0.06, 0.24, 0.23, 0.31, 0.94, 0.15, 0.17, 1.03, 0.58, 0.93, 0.19, 0, 0.2, 0.14, 0.32, 1.5, 0.61, 0.23, 0.74, 0.26, 0.83, 0.3, 0.12, 0.09, 0.38, 1.25, 0.16, 0.39, 0.37, 5.68, 0.03, 0.33, 0.1, 0.31, 0.42, 0.34, 0.24, 0.15, 0.18, 0.18, 0.44, 0, 0.63, 0.22, 2.04, 0.23, 3.15, 0.17, 0.54, 0.03, 0.04, 0.46, 0.2, 0.13, 0.18, 0.9, 0.68, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.13, 0.21, 5.81, 0.39, 0.14, 0.57, 0.88, 0.39, 0.1, 0.57, 0.32, 0.04, 0, 0.03, 0.82, 0, 0.19, 0.17)
df <- data.frame(Y = dependent_var, X = independent_var)
ggplot(aes(x=independent_var, y=dependent_var), data=df) + geom_point()

lmMod <- lm(Y ~ X, data=df)
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) # init 4 charts in 1 panel
plot(lmMod)
lmtest::bptest(lmMod)
```

Comment: "making the variance the largest there" Not really. The observation with the second highest x value has the largest residual. I would say your issue isn't really heteroscedasticity. You have insufficient observations for high x values and an influential observation as a result. But the main issue is extremely poor explanatory power. Overall, I would reject this model as being useful because the adjusted R² is only 0.03. You seem to be missing the most important predictors.

Comment: Are you saying the data is not heteroscedastic then? I'm a bit puzzled because by visual inspection the data don't look homoscedastic either. Or, can it be the case that the bptest fails to reject null because there is insufficient number of data points on the high x values?

Comment: I understand that this predictor is not a good one. This is one of many predictors and I want to exclude this predictor (and many similar predictors as this one) from the model, but I think I need a good reason to do that. I thought I could use heteroscedasticity as a criterion.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Why are you fitting a model with only one predictor then, especially if you “want to exclude” it?

Comment: I am not fitting the model only with this predictor. I'm just drawing this plot to find an objective reason to exclude this predictor. (I can't say I excluded this variable because I don't like it). Anyways, that's not the original question. The original question is why bptest doesn't find this data to be heteroscedastic (i.e., how the test works)